# how to remove characters in a string till the first occurrence of a string,

Tags: tcl

For ex=> set a 123/345/567/2345  , now i want to remove 123 and keep rest

expected output is `345/567/2345`

How to do this in tcl without the use of `awk '{print $1}'`

```
set string 123/456/789
set idx [string last "/" $string]
set wanted [string range $string $idx-3 end]
```

Saw this approach in one of the posts but i want to make it so that
12345/43444/567676 should give me output as 43444/567676

Comment: Are you really working with filenames? If you are, use `file split`. It handles weird edge cases. (If you aren't, don't.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `string first`, not string last. And add 1 to `idx` to ignore the leading forward slash.

```
set string 12345/43444/567676
set idx [string first "/" $string]
set wanted [string range $string $idx+1 end]
```

Outputs:

```
43444/567676
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
set input "123/345/567/2345"
regexp {^[^/]*/(.*)$} $input matched output
puts $output  ;# 345/567/2345
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using list operations:

```
(Tcl) 1 % set string 123/456/789
123/456/789
(Tcl) 2 % set list [split $string / ]
123 456 789
(Tcl) 3 % set l2 [lassign $list dummy]
456 789
(Tcl) 4 % set wanted [join $l2 / ]
456/789
```

Or the same thing as a one-liner:

```
set wanted [join [lassign [split $string / ] dummy] / ]
```

Comment: `[lrange $list 1 end]` is also available.

Comment: In case it's not clear to the OP, this is a more straightforward way to return the list minus its first element, which I did with `[lassign $list dummy]` .

Comment: Is it dummy variable that return the list minus its first element, which you did with `[lassign $list dummy]` Or what exactly happens here ?

Comment: @flash - see the documentation for details - https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm